# How can I change one single colour on Mac OS X screen (similar to invert colours)?

Tags: macos, graphics, colors, accessibility

I've read some guys have done a trick editing this file, but I'm not a guru.

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreGraphics \
(DisplayUseInvertedPolarity -bool YES)
```

Basically I want to change the white background color to sepia or anything darker when I read in Skim pdf reader. Since Skim (unlike Kindle) doesnt support this feature, maybe I find a work around and I can change the white color of the screen so it will be useful with any application I want if I can make this happen.

Comment: Are you finding something like this  http://mattgemmell.com/2009/11/02/shady-for-tired-eyes/  ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you only want a work around to add Kindle's sepia mode everywhere, I would suggest you to http://justgetflux.com/‎ instead of trying to achieve what you want by hand.